# Handle destructoring in macro that creates defmethod methods

Tags: clojure, macros, destructuring

In my use case, I have a multimethod that takes two arguments, both of them maps. The first one is used, amongst other things, to compute the dispatch value. The second one is a kind of context variable that will be returned either modified or unmodified by the implementing methods.

```clj
(defmulti code (fn [input _] (:cmd input)))

; example implementation
(defmethod code "foo" [_ {var :var :as ctx}]
  {:out (str "foo; ctx.var=" var)
   :ctx ctx})
```

As you can see, in this example implementation I return the context variable unmodified. Since I have a lot of implementations that do not modify the context, I decided to write a macro that writes the defmethod for me, putting the computation output under the key `:out` and the unmodified context under `:ctx`:

```clj
(defmacro stable-ctx [multifn dispatch-val args impl]
  `(defmethod ~multifn ~dispatch-val ~args
     {:out ~impl
      :ctx (second ~args)}))
```

This works nicely for the following implementations:

```clj
(stable-ctx code "bar" [_ _] "bar")

(stable-ctx code "foo2" [_ ctx] (str "foo2; ctx.var=" (:var ctx)))
```

However, it is obvious that it fails if I use destructoring within my definition:

```clj
(stable-ctx code "foo3" [_ {var :var}] (str "foo3; ctx.var=" var))
```

(The output for `(code {:cmd "foobar"} {:var 2})` is `{:out "foobar; ctx.var=2", :ctx {2 :var}}` instead of `{:out "foobar; ctx.var=2", :ctx {:var 2}}`)

I would like to know how I could solve this issue. I suspect the clojure.core/destructure function could help me with this, but sadly it is missing a documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a different, private name for the context argument, and `let` the name the client wants. They can do whatever they want with their name, you'll still have yours.

```
(defmacro stable-ctx [multifn dispatch-val [a b] impl]
  `(defmethod ~multifn ~dispatch-val [~a y#]
     (let [~b y#]
       {:out ~impl
        :ctx y#})))
```

Here `b` and `y#` are two names for the same thing, but `y#` is known to be a gensymmed symbol that you created, and so is safe to return. `b` is whatever the client put in the arg vector, and so may be destructured if they like.

Comment: Thank you very much! I like this elegant solution. I did not know about the gensym concept, so there is something new for me to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am missing something, but you could always move the destructuring into the `impl` code like:

```
(stable-ctx code "foo3" [args]
  (let [{var :var}  (second args)]
    (str "foo3; ctx.var=" var)))
```

Comment: You should try macroexpanding this. It doesn't expand into what the question asks for. But that's an easy fix; the more important issue is that it leaves annoying boilerplate in the client code, which is exactly what the macro is supposed to alleviate.